# Beginner looping issue- while ... do

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

What the program does: Reads two values from input, asks user whether to add, subtract, or find the product. If user enters one of the three options, it calculates, otherwise the program will loop back to the beginning. The program should STOP after calculation if the user enters one of the three options.

I'm not sure why it keeps on looping. How do I make the script loop only when the user types in a string other than "sum", "difference", or "product"? Also, how can I make the code simpler? Is there any way to loop the program without using do ... while?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class simp_calculator
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    double a, b;
    String response;
    boolean noresponse;

    do
    {
      System.out.println ("Please enter first number.");
      a = scan.nextDouble();

      System.out.println ("Please enter second number.");
      b = scan.nextDouble();

      System.out.println ("Would you like to find the sum, difference, product?");
      response = scan.next();

      if (response.equalsIgnoreCase ("sum"))
      {
        System.out.println (a + b);
      }

      if (response.equalsIgnoreCase ("difference"))
      {
        System.out.println (a - b);
      }

      if (response.equalsIgnoreCase ("product"))
      {
        System.out.println (a * b);
      }

      else
      {
        noresponse = true; 
        System.out.println ("Starting again...");
      }

    }
    while (noresponse = true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the assignment operator, `=`, so `noresponse` will always be `true`.  The result of the assignment expression is thus `true`.

You want to *check* if it is `true`, so use the comparison operator `==`:

```
while (noresponse == true);
```

or, because it's already a `boolean`:

```
while (noresponse);
```

Also, you may be getting a compiler error that `noresponse` may not have been initialized.  You will need to make sure that it's initialized in all cases, and that something sets it to `false` so the loop will eventually end.

Answer (score 2):

change `while (noresponse = true);` to `while (noresponse == true);`.
`=` is an assignment operation - where as `==` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1. Currently you are looping while `noreponse` equals true. So to exit that loop, you need to set`noresponse` to false when a particular condition is met :) I could give you the answer, but you should be able to figure it out with the info I've given you. (hint: at some point you need to set `noresonse` to false).
2. Also, you are setting `noresponse` to equal, rather than comparing it. You need to use `==` to compare.

So make while `(noresponse = true);` into `while (noresponse == true);`.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

- The `else` applies only to the last if; so for any value, other that "product", `noresponse` becomes `true` and the loop goes on. Replace all your `if`s from the second on with `else if`s.
- `noresponse` should be given the value `false` at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

just change `while (reponse = true)` to `while(reponse)` and name the variable ..